# Joi validation: How to require at least one key in an object payload

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, joi

Joi doesn't seem to be respecting the `.or` condition in the following validation:

```
export const PAYLOAD = Joi.object().keys({
  PUSH_UP:        Joi.any(),
  INVERTED_ROW:   Joi.any(),
  DIP:            Joi.any(),
  CHIN_UP:        Joi.any(),
  PULL_UP:        Joi.any(),
  GOBLET_SQUAT:   Joi.any(),
  BACK_EXTENSION: Joi.any()
}).or('PUSH_UP', 'INVERTED_ROW', 'DIP', 'CHIN_UP', 'PULL_UP', 'GOBLET_SQUAT', 'BACK_EXTENSION')
```

The incoming payload should have one or more of those object keys in it.  In this case, the payload is as follow:

```
{
  "BACK_EXTENSION": {
    "reps": 30,
    "exerciseId": 7
  },
  "PUSH_UP": {
    "reps": 1,
    "exerciseId": 1
  }
}
```

response:

```
ValidationError: "INVERTED_ROW" is required
```

Based upon the docs (https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.9.1#objectorpeers-options), I would expect this to work.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned "One or more". So I am assuming you don't care which one of the key is present.

```
export const PAYLOAD = Joi.object().keys({
  PUSH_UP:        Joi.any(),
  INVERTED_ROW:   Joi.any(),
  DIP:            Joi.any(),
  CHIN_UP:        Joi.any(),
  PULL_UP:        Joi.any(),
  GOBLET_SQUAT:   Joi.any(),
  BACK_EXTENSION: Joi.any()
}).min(1);
```